# How to find matched key and return values of it in js object

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, return-value, key-value

I have a Javascript object like this :

```
Const dataStructure = {
1 : 2000, 
2 : 1950,
// and so on
```

On the other side I have a userInput, 
I want to find the matched key for it and get the value of that key to send it as a response ti user.

So I go through different solutions(for, forIn and...), but I couldn't retrieve the value

I appreciat your answers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It's just a bunch of numeric keys; get a number and return the value at that key.

Comment: And we appreciate if you share with us what you've tried, since we avoid to just write full code, we prefer to guide and help to fix issues

Answer (score 0):

If your user input is saved to var USER_INPUT, you could do something like the following:

```
console.log(dataStructure[USER_INPUT])
```